# How do I move the text inside the button, it only moves when I click on the text and not when I click the button? Ref. (.button_text, .button_icon)

Tags: html, css, button

```css
.button__text {
    position:relative;
  
    transform:translate3d(0px, -4px, 0px);
    margin:0;
    align-self:end;
    grid-column:1/5;
    grid-row:2;

    text-align:center;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight:550;
    background-color: #aaaa;
    color: transparent;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    transition: .13s ease-in-out;
}

.button__text:active {
    transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sense when the button has been clicked and then alter the translation of the text.

Here's a simple snippet - when the button has :active then its child gets the altered positioning.

```css
.button__text {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -4px, 0px);
  margin: 0;
  align-self: end;
  grid-column: 1/5;
  grid-row: 2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 550;
  background-color: #aaaa;
  color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  transition: .13s ease-in-out;
}

button:active .button__text {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<button><div class="button__text">click me</div></button>
```